# Kubectl logs hangs for hours and then returns to works normally

Tags: logging, kubernetes, hangs

Kubectl logs hanginging for hours and shows something like:

> Unable to connect to the server: read tcp
>   192.168.69.227:57692->35.188.160.72:443: read: connection reset by peer

We have no idea how to start debugging this problem that happens often.
We were able to enter in the nodes and use the command docker logs containername.

Last time this ocurred we restarted all the nodes. But today we decided to wait and try to debug, after some hours the logs worked again.
But we would like to figure out why this is japenning.

We are using GCE, cluster version `1.8.3-gke.0` with ubuntu.

Any ideas of what could be happening or how to start debugging this problem?